# Tag Excerpts and Descriptions, OK to copy Wikipedia?

Tags: support, tag-wiki

Is it OK to copy text from Wikipedia when filling out Tag excerpts and descriptions?

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia is dual-licensed under the GFDL and CC BY-SA 3.0 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Copyrights); stack exchange content is also under the CC BY-SA 3.0, so *provided attribution is given* (eg, a link to the *specific revision* in wikipedia so the edit history can be checked) it shouldn't be a problem.